# Complex model in SwifUI

Tags: swiftui

I have a multilevel model like:

```
class TaskDto : Identifiable, Equatable, ObservableObject {

var id: String
@Published var fileName:String
@Published var name: String
.... more stuff
@Published var parameters : JobParametersDto }
```

And

```
class JobParametersDto : Identifiable, Equatable, ObservableObject {

var id: String

@Published var blobs: [BlobRequestDto]
@Published var commands:[CommandDto]
@Published var mainTask: String
```

}

And so on, several embedded levels.

There is a number of views, each for one structure

```
struct BlobView: View {

@ObservedObject var taskDto: TaskDto


static let blobNames = [
    "Product",
    "Id",
    "Name",
    "Version",
    "Limit",
    "Unzip"]

let columns = Array(repeating: GridItem(.flexible(minimum: 100)), count: filterNames.count)
@State private var scrollViewContentSize: CGSize = .zero

var body: some View {
    
    GridView(title: "Blob Names")
    {
        LazyVGrid(columns: columns) {
            ForEach (Self.blobNames, id: \.self) {
                blobName in
                Text("\(blobName)").bold()
            }
            
            ForEach($taskDto.parameters.blobs ) {
                blob in
                if(! blob.Removed.wrappedValue) {
                   
                    TextField("", text: f blob.BlobId)
                    
                    TextField("", text: blob.BlobName)
                    TextField("", text: blob.BlobVersion)

                    Toggle("", isOn: filter.Unzip)
                      
                }
            }
        } //grid
    }
}
```

The problem is when any field in the model changes the views do not reflect the change. For example I have a Toggle at the end of the View code. It does not update when I click on it until I click on another field.

Obviously this arrangement is not very valid. What is the right way to organize a model with embedded models in SiwftUI ?

Comment: Some observations: you have deep nested `ObservableObject`, that somethimes creates problems when 
updating them. Usually you need to do it manually, for example: `self.model.objectWillChange.send()`.
I noticed that you have some mistakes in your code, e.g. `TextField("", text: f blob.BlobId)` 
I conclude from that, that what you are showing us is not the code you use. Also what does `filter.Unzip` do?
Have a look at this link, it gives you examples of how to use `ObservableObject` and manage data in your app https://developer.apple.com/documentation/swiftui/managing-model-data-in-your-app

Answer (score 0):

In Swift and SwiftUI we use structs for the model types. This solves alot of the consistency issues we had with objects in ObjC. [See Choosing Between Structures and Classes (Apple Developer Documentation)](https://developer.apple.com/documentation/swift/choosing-between-structures-and-classes)

We usually use a single object to persist or sync these model structs, usually its an environment object, a singleton, there are 2 singletons: one shared and one preview.

Comment: In the suggestion above and link to apple documentation: https://developer.apple.com/documentation/swiftui/managing-model-data-in-your-app I seem to follow the same pattern but having huge problems with updates. I will try structs. Also I cannot use singletons or environment objects as it is a multi document application and there can be multiple models. I am a but baffled but the design decision of SwiftUI to use environment objects and singletons for data objects. To me it looks like decades of advancement in programming were discarded and we started all over again.